Why won't my matrix remain Hermitian?
I have a $4\times 4$ Hermitian matrix  called $A_{x}$ whose elements are labelled $a_{ij}$ $(i,j = 1, 2, 3, 4)$. (See definitions below.) The $a_{ij}$'s are functions of two variables $x$ and $y$ and are made up of trigonometric functions.
Using this matrix I need to calculate a matrix called $R_{01}$ where
$$R_{01} = \sqrt{\sqrt{A_{x}}\cdot \tilde A_{x}\cdot\sqrt{A_{x}}},$$
and where
$$\tilde A_{x} = \sigma_{y}\otimes\sigma_{y}\cdot A_{x}^{*}\cdot\sigma_{y}\otimes\sigma_{y}\quad\left(\sigma_{2}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
            0 & -i \\\\
            i & 0
        \end{bmatrix}\right),$$
Here, $A_{x}^{*}$ is given by
$$A_{x}^{*} = \sum_{i=1}^{4}\sum_{j=1}^{4}|{e_{i}}><e_{j}|\cdot A_{x}\cdot |e_{i}><e_{j}|$$
where
$$|e_{1}>=\frac{1}{2}(|R,R> + |L,L>)$$
$$|e_{2}>=\frac{i}{2}(|R,R> - |L,L>)$$
$$|e_{3}>=\frac{i}{2}(|R,L> + |L,R>)$$
$$|e_{4}>=\frac{1}{2}(|R,L> - |L,R>)$$
The matrix $R_{01}$ should also be Hermitian for all values of $x$ and $y$, where $0\le x\le 2\pi$  and $0\le y\le \pi$. But I am finding that this is not always the case.
The code below contains an "if" statement that checks for which values of $x$ and $y$ (given in degrees) when $R_{01}$ is not Hermitian. It does this by taking the difference between $R_{01}$ and its transpose complex conjugate $R_{01}^{\dagger}$. If the difference does not return the zero matrix it will output what the difference matrix looks like.
I feel that if I could use Mathematica to calculate the analytical solution for $R_{01}$ then perhaps this non-Hermitian problem would go away. I did try to get Mathematica to calculate the analytical solution of $\sqrt{A_{x}}$. But after running the code for 6 hours I gave up.
Can someone propose a way to solve this non-Hermitian problem?
Thank you so much for your time.
ClearAll[x, y];

Ket[R] = ({{1},{0}});
Bra[R] = ({{1, 0}});
Ket[L] = ({{0},{1}});
Bra[L] = ({{00, 1}});

Ket[R, R] = KroneckerProduct[Ket[R], Ket[R]];
Ket[R, L] = KroneckerProduct[Ket[R], Ket[L]];
Ket[L, R] = KroneckerProduct[Ket[L], Ket[R]];
Ket[L, L] = KroneckerProduct[Ket[L], Ket[L]];

Bra[R, R] = KroneckerProduct[Bra[R], Bra[R]];
Bra[R, L] = KroneckerProduct[Bra[R], Bra[L]];
Bra[L, R] = KroneckerProduct[Bra[L], Bra[R]];
Bra[L, L] = KroneckerProduct[Bra[L], Bra[L]];

Ket[e1] = 1/2*(Ket[R, R] + Ket[L, L]);
Ket[e2] = I/2*(Ket[R, R] - Ket[L, L]);
Ket[e3] = I/2*(Ket[R, L] + Ket[L, R]);
Ket[e4] = 1/2*(Ket[R, L] - Ket[L, R]);

Bra[e1] = 1/2*(Bra[R, R] + Bra[L, L]);
Bra[e2] = -I/2*(Bra[R, R] - Bra[L, L]);
Bra[e3] = -I/2*(Bra[R, L] + Bra[L, R]);
Bra[e4] = 1/2*(Bra[R, L] - Bra[L, R]);

a11 = (-3 + Cos[x] Sin[y] + Cos[y]^3 Cos[x] Sin[y] + 
     Cos[y]^2 (1 - 3 Cos[x] Sin[y]) + 
     Cos[y] (-2 + Cos[x] Sin[y]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + 
     Cos[3 y]);

a21 = ((-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[
      y] ((-1 + Cos[y]) Cos[x] + Sin[y] - 
       2 I Sin[y/2]^2 Sin[x]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + 
     Cos[3 y]);

a31 = (Cos[
      y/2] (-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[y/2]^2 (4 Cos[y/2] + 
       6 Cos[y/2]^2 Cos[x] Sin[y/2] + 
       Sin[y/2] ((-3 + Cos[y]) Cos[x] - 4 I Sin[x])) (-Cos[2 x] + 
       I Sin[2 x]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]);

a41 = -(((-2 + Cos[y]) (1 + Cos[y])^2 (Cos[2 x] - I Sin[2 x]))/(-18 + 
       15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]));

a12 = ((-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[
      y] ((-1 + Cos[y]) Cos[x] + Sin[y] - 
       I (-1 + Cos[y]) Sin[x]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + 
     Cos[3 y]);

a22 = -(((-1 + Cos[y])^2 (3 - Cos[x] Sin[y] + 
         Cos[y] (-2 + Cos[x] Sin[y])))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] +
        Cos[3 y]));

a32 = ((-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[y/2]^4 (-4 Cos[2 x] + 4 I Sin[2 x]))/(-18 + 
     15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]);

a42 = (Cos[
      y/2] (-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[y/2]^2 (-4 Cos[y/2] + 
       6 Cos[y/2]^2 Cos[x] Sin[y/2] + 
       Sin[y/2] ((-3 + Cos[y]) Cos[x] - 4 I Sin[x])) (Cos[2 x] - 
       I Sin[2 x]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]);

a13 = -((Cos[
        y/2] (-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[y/2]^2 (4 Cos[y/2] + 
         6 Cos[y/2]^2 Cos[x] Sin[y/2] + 
         Sin[y/2] ((-3 + Cos[y]) Cos[x] + 4 I Sin[x])) (Cos[2 x] + 
         I Sin[2 x]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]));

a23 = -((4 (-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[y/2]^4 (Cos[2 x] + I Sin[2 x]))/(-18 + 
       15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]));

a33 = ((-1 + Cos[y])^2 (-3 - Cos[x] Sin[y] + 
       Cos[y] (2 + Cos[x] Sin[y])))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + 
     Cos[3 y]);

a43 = ((-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[
      y] (-(-1 + Cos[y]) Cos[x] + Sin[y] - 
       I (-1 + Cos[y]) Sin[x]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + 
     Cos[3 y]);

a14 = -(((-2 + Cos[y]) (1 + Cos[y])^2 (Cos[2 x] + I Sin[2 x]))/(-18 + 
       15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]));

a24 = (Cos[
      y/2] (-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[y/2]^2 (-4 Cos[y/2] + 
       6 Cos[y/2]^2 Cos[x] Sin[y/2] + 
       Sin[y/2] ((-3 + Cos[y]) Cos[x] + 4 I Sin[x])) (Cos[2 x] + 
       I Sin[2 x]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]);

a34 = ((-2 + Cos[y]) Sin[
      y] (Cos[x] - Cos[y] Cos[x] + Sin[y] - I Sin[x] + 
       I Cos[y] Sin[x]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] + Cos[3 y]);

a44 = -((3 + Cos[x] Sin[y] + Cos[y]^3 Cos[x] Sin[y] + 
       Cos[y] (2 + Cos[x] Sin[y]) - 
       Cos[y]^2 (1 + 3 Cos[x] Sin[y]))/(-18 + 15 Cos[y] - 6 Cos[2 y] +
        Cos[3 y]));

Ax[x_, y_] = ({{a11, a12, a13, a14}, {a21, a22, a23, a24}, {a31, a32, 
     a33, a34}, {a41, a42, a43, a44}});

threshold = 10^-1;
thetamax = 180;
phimax = 360;
For[y = 0, y <= thetamax, y += 10, 
 For[x = 0, x <= phimax, x += 10, yrad = y*Pi/180;
  xrad = x*Pi/180;
  AxEval = N[Ax[yrad, xrad], 10];
  (*Pauli-Y matrix for a 2-qubit system*)
  PauliY = PauliMatrix[2];
  SYY = KroneckerProduct[PauliY, PauliY];
  AxStar = 
   Simplify[
    Sum[Sum[(Ket[Symbol["e" <> ToString[i]]].Bra[
         Symbol["e" <> ToString[j]]].AxEval.Ket[
         Symbol["e" <> ToString[i]]].Bra[
         Symbol["e" <> ToString[j]]]), {j, 4}], {i, 4}]];
  AxTilda = SYY.AxStar.SYY;
  sqrtAx = MatrixPower[AxEval, 1/2];
  R01 = Chop[MatrixPower[sqrtAx.AxTilda.sqrtAx, 1/2], threshold];
  ConTranR01 = ConjugateTranspose[R01];
  diff = Chop[FullSimplify[R01 - ConTranR01], threshold];
  If[diff != ({{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
       0}}), Print[StringForm["Diff[``,``]=", x, y], 
    diff // MatrixForm];
   eigenvalues = Chop[Eigenvalues[R01], threshold];
   Print[StringForm["Eigenvalues[``,``]=", x, y], 
    eigenvalues // MatrixForm];
   Print[StringForm["    "]];];
  
  ]]



Is it just me or if you restart MMA and scrape that block of code off the screen and paste it into MMA does it complain about something being incomplete? I've even tried things like getting rid of your StringForm and other things that do not seem absolutely essential and I still cannot scrape-n-paste-n-evaluate and get that to run.

Hi Bill, I found what the problem was (there was a quantity called Rf01 instead of R01). I have fixed the code and checked it. It runs fine on Mathematica 12.1. Sorry about that!

Na, no sorries, not for me. You found and fixed your problem. I don't think I really helped, but you got your problem solved in spite of me. Good.

Hi Bill. The problem is not fixed. The matrix R01 is still not Hermitian. But thanks for taking the time to try and help.

AxStar is calculated based on Ax[x,y], but it should be AxEval, or no?  Note that Bra and Ket are keywords.   Other thoughts -- An earlier version of AxStar used Conjugate, possibly improperly.  Use this answer instead.  Use ComplexExpand instead of $Assumptions, when possible.

Hi LouisB, Thank you for picking up the Ax[x,y] typo. I have corrected that and updated the code. The earlier version did use Conjugate for AxStar but it turned out that I was using the incorrect definition for AxStar. The definition in the updated code is the correct definition. So I removed the $Assumption line as I don't need it anymore. As for the Ket key words, I have explicitly tested all the definitions using the Ket and Bra and they all work as expected. Sadly, though, I still get cases where R01 behaves non-Hermitian for some values of x and y.  Thanks for your help, though.

I've not looked at this in detail, but: 1. A numeric matrix that should be Hermitian can become non-Hermitian through rounding errors.  The solution is to use the closest Hermitian matrix X->(X+ConjugateTranspose[X])/2.  2. Look at the difference X-ConjugateTranspose[X] to check whether it nearly is Hermitian.

Thank you, thank you, thank you, mikado! I  believe you may have solved the puzzle. I've tried it for $R_{01}\mapsto (R_{01}+R_{01}^{\dagger})/2$ and it seems like the problem has gone. I will run a few more tests to make sure then will update the code accordingly just in case it helps others. Cheers!
